# Can anyone help my first WebView i am stucked witht this issue ? Unfortunately <app name> has stopped

Tags: php, android, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

1-content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:context="mx.newmx.MainActivity"
            tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">   
            <WebView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview" /> 
 </RelativeLayout>
```

2-manifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="mx.newmx">
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
<activity
android:name="mx.newmx.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

3-MainActivity.java file code

```
package mx.newmx;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView myWebView ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
.setAction("Action", null).show();
}
});
myWebView = (WebView) myWebView.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.moneyx.pk/");
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();
//noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

4-my log pls check this

```
03-04 14:48:25.448 7418-7418/mx.newmx W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
03-04 14:48:25.468 7418-7418/mx.newmx D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-04 14:48:25.469 7418-7418/mx.newmx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: mx.newmx, PID: 7418
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mx.newmx/mx.newmx.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.webkit.WebView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.webkit.WebView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
at mx.newmx.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

this is how i am creating my first WebView but this gives error unfortunatily app name has stopped , please anyone check where is the issue wit the code so i can proceed

this is how i am creating my first WebView but this gives error unfortunatily app name has stopped , please anyone check where is the issue wit the code so i can proceed

Comment: check what is `java.lang.NullPointerException:` on stackoverflow. You're getting this exception.

Comment: can you pls help out what is the issue?

Comment: `myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);`

Answer (score 0):

```
myWebView = (WebView) myWebView.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
```

remove myWebView use only findViewById like this

```
 myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating different layout. Please check

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: What it would be can you please explain?

Comment: I think you inflated different layout in the activity which doesn't contains webview.. please check

Comment: still same i have change this also no luck